# Primefaces is not immediately closing the stream of DefaultStreamedContent after read

Tags: jsf, file-io, primefaces, stream

I have the following problem:

I am displaying an image in my webapp using a `<p:graphicImage>` from Primefaces

The image displayed is delivered by a bean as a `DefaultStreamedContent`. In my application I am sometimes deleting images displayed this way during runtime.

This always takes a little time till I can delete the image. After debugging a little i used the `Files.delete` of Java 7 and got the following exception:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I thus suspect that Primefaces is not immediately closing the stream behind the `DefaultStreamedContent` after displaying and i am not able to delete the file whenever I want.

Is there any way to tell the `DefaultStreamedContent` to close itself imediately after read (I already looked into the documentation and didn't find any fitting method within the `DefaultStreamedContent`, but maybe one can tell the stream or something like that?)

Comment: PrimeFaces closes them. This problem suggests that you're storing images inside expanded WAR folder instead of outside. Is this true?

Comment: The images are stored outside the WAR folder in my drive at the moment (running on localhost) at some folder on C://..../images

Comment: As evidence of close, check line 94 of `PrimeResourceHandler` in PrimeFaces version 3.5. As to delete fail, is this file been created by another process beforehand or so?

Comment: Went through `PrimeResourceHandler` in debug mode and it does enter the close clause so it should be closed. Im am previously uploading the picture that i receive through through a `UploadedFile` and getting the `byte[]` out of it and saving it into a file with `FileOutputStream`. this looks somethign like this:
fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
fos.write(content);
fos.flush();
fos.close();

Shouldn't this be enough to make it able to be deleted again?

Comment: After my weekend I now checked what process is keeping the file opened with the Process Explorer from Microsoft technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx but it seemed as that no Process is keeping the file opened.

Comment: When you don't use PrimeFaces streamed content, can you still delete the image?

Comment: Found the solution :) Look at the answer

Comment: Curious. Good find though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I finally found out what is happening using the `Unlocker` tool

(can be downloaded here: http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/#download)

I saw that the `java.exe` is locking the file once it is displayed. Therefor the `Stream` behind the `StreamedContent` is NOT immediately closed after reading.

My solution was as follows:

I made a superclass extending the `StreamedContent` and let it read the inputstream and "feed" the read bytes into a new `InputStream`. After that i closed the given stream so that the ressource behind it is released again.

the class looks something like this:

```
public class PersonalStreamedContent extends DefaultStreamedContent {

/**
 * Copies the given Inputstream and closes it afterwards
 */
public PersonalStreamedContent(FileInputStream stream, String contentType) {
    super(copyInputStream(stream), contentType);
}

public static InputStream copyInputStream(InputStream stream) {
    if (stream != null) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
            stream.close();
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("inputStream was null");
    }
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[] {});
}
}
```

I am quite sure that the image is retrieved 2 times by `Primefaces` but only closed the FIRST time it is loaded. I didn't realize this in the beginning.

I hope this can help some other people too :)

Comment: Dude, i must say how much i love ya! It works like a charm!! I was trying to figure out wtf locked the file using the DefaultStream... but u gave us the awnser!! Thanks!! Damm u DefaultStrem that doesnt close the inputstream :/